# How to calculate availability on blockchain/IPFS and Hadoop/HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, blockchain, ipfs, availability

I am working on a thesis proposal how to optimize big data architecture using blockchain/IPFS, by comparing the amount of data availability on Blockchain/IPFS and Hadoop/HDFS, the challenge is how do I calculate or measure availability on both architectures?

Comment: HDFS already calculates availability.... `1 - (Space used`/`Total space` `) %`

Comment: Can we use the same equation to calculate the availability of ipfs?

Comment: Never used it, but `1-usage/capacity` is a global formula for calculating storage availability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a thesis of IPFS + Hadoop for Big Data analysis.
[https://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~hpaik/thesis/showcases/16s2/scott_brisbane.pdf](https://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/%7Ehpaik/thesis/showcases/16s2/scott_brisbane.pdf) (1 slide summing up)
https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/scott-brisbane-thesis/decentralising-big-data-processing.pdf (actual paper)